# Accessing URL with params in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I am new in Spring Security and have an issue with authenticating specific URLs with path variables or parameters.

Let's say I have some URL: `/messages/1` where 1 is an user's ID.

What I want to do is to let ONLY user with ID=1 accessing page with this URL.

Spring Security allows accessing some content if user is authenticated, but how can I make authentication more narrow?

Comment: By page do you mean JSP? Also if you want to narrow access you are best to use Roles ACL [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/) is a good example.

Comment: I use Thymeleaf instead of JSP.

Comment: I saw that example, but it just explains how to configure role-based authentication. It's not a point of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have an `id` property in your `UserDetails`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/messages/{userId}", method=HttpMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("#userId == authentication.principal.id")
public List<Message> getMessages(@PathVariable String userId) {
    // retrieve from DAO here
}
```

Make sure you have enabled pre/post-annotations in your security config.