# Insecure Object Reference in java web application

Tags: java, security, spring-security

I am creating a web application in java. It deals with several business Objects being modeled in the application. Each object has table associated with it in database. I want to show the details of particular object, say for eg. Student to User. For that I am making ajax request to server and passing UserId as input parameter. The psuedocode looks something like given below :

```
1) Get StudentId from request.
2) Fetch Student details from db for given studentId
3) Send the student data as response to the user
```

What I want is, StudentId must not be used and instead of that a random number or anything else can be used, that can be mapped to student id at server side and consequently student details are fetched and send to client. I want this so that even if studentId is doctored/modified by user, as part of query string, user doesn't get any other student data and thus, error message is show to it.

Comment: Why not validate that the current user is allowed to access the given student instead?

Comment: Maybe useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817200/accessing-url-with-params-in-spring-security

Comment: Use Spring Security ACL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one shot solution is use owasp esapi access reference map, you will love it :)

https://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/AccessReferenceMap.html

Answer (score 1):

Without some form of authentication, an attacker would be able to simply try different values for StudentId until they find one that works. By repeating this, they would be able to enumerate the different StudentIds and retrieve all the student data. A user should only be able to access the records they have access to. I would strongly recommend implementing a solid authentication method.

However, if you cannot implement an authentication mechanism, you can try to make the enumeration process more difficult. One way to do this would be to randomly assign StudentIds (To avoid the [German Tank Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem)), and make them as long as is practical. Something like a long, random string would make an excellent ID. Note that the more users you have, the less effective this will be at "safeguarding" your data. In addition, this method does not actually secure your data,  it merely makes it (theoretically) more difficult for an attacker to retrieve all of it. If they guess the right ID, they can still get data they shouldn't.

In addition, since you are using Java, you can use [PreparedStatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and parameter binding to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Note that [GUIDs are unique, not random](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120523-00/?p=7553/). The same goes for UUIDs - the specification doesn't actually state they have to be generated from a cryptographically secure pseudo random number generator.